# How to set dropdown list to default value after selecting particular option in angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have dropdownlist which contains list of cities (Default selection is --Select City--). When a user selects a city, that city gets added into some div. Once it is added it should set to its default value i.e --Select City--.

Is there a way to achieve this? Without Page reload?

Comment: post whatever you have tried

Comment: Hello @Sajeetharan I am working on live project so cant post code over here. Any suggestion what can i use to reset that dropdown to its default value? Thanks in adv

Comment: Minor grammar and spelling corrections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this :**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope) {
    $scope.cities = [
     {"id":1,"name":"Delhi"},
     {"id":2,"name":"Hyderabad"},
     {"id":3,"name":"Pune"}
    ];
    
    $scope.selectedCities = [];
    $scope.setCity = function(city) {
      $scope.selectedCity = "";
      $scope.selectedCities.push(city);
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <select ng-model="selectedCity" ng-options="option.name as option.name for option in cities" ng-change="setCity(selectedCity)">
    <option value="">--Select City--</option>
  </select>
  <div ng-repeat="cityName in selectedCities">
   {{cityName}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken what you have to do is to assign the model of select input to some other model and then reset the initial model to its default value which is `null`.

This could be done with a function using `ng-change` directive.

Something like:

```
$scope.select = function() {
    $scope.selectedCity = $scope.city;
    $scope.city = null;
  }
```

Then in the view:

```
<select ng-change="select()" ng-model="city" ng-options="option for option in options">
      <option value="">Select City</option>
    </select>
```

Here's a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mfjawaey/) for you.